# Creating TreeView in QML only

Tags: qt, qml, treeview

I am trying to create a very simple TreeView using QML only.  Sadly the documentation/examples in this area are pretty weak. I have attempted to build a simple tree as shown below.  My code fails with

> Could not resolve the prototype "ListModel" or "MyDataModel"

Can someone turn this into a hierarchical data model shown in simple tree?  Or provide a link to a (purely QML) example?

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    TreeView {
        itemDelegate: myDelegate
        model: MyDataModel {}
    }

    Component {
        id: myDelegate
        Row {
            Text { text: label }
        }
    }
}
```

MyDataModel.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.12

ListModel {
    ListElement {
        label: "ABC"
        subList: [
            ListElement {
                label: "aaa"
            },
            ListElement {
                label: "bbb"
            }
        ]
    }
    ListElement {
        label: "DEF"
        subList: [
            ListElement {
                label: "ccc"
            },
            ListElement {
                label: "ddd"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change it to use `model: MyDataModel {}`?

Comment: That gives error "Could not resolve the prototype "ListModel" of "MyDataModel".  If I get rid of the MyDataModel and just leave {} it runs, but obviously no tree is present so no data in the model

Comment: I'm not sure what that error means, but it's at least trying to use your model now. You weren't using an instance of your MyDataModel before. You were just passing the `MyDataModel` *type* to the `model` property.

Comment: It won't run due to error I mentioned above. I have updated the question to reflect the error, but still something wrong with the data model

Comment: Right, I know it doesn't solve your problem yet. But it's a step forward.

Comment: I guess the docs is pretty clear - _The TreeView accept models derived from the QAbstractItemModel class_.  `ListModel` isn't `QAbstractItemModel` descendant. As I know QML only solution is not possible with tree.

Comment: @TSG Definitely, `TreeView` requires `TreeModel` declared in C++. But in your example I can see you use only 2 level hierarchy. Maybe it will fit your requirements, at least as a workaround you can use code snippet from here: https://felgo.com/developers/forums/t/applistview-with-collapsible-sections-headers

You can skip Felgo's components and use your own (e..g `AppListView` -> `ListView`, `SimpleSection`-> `Rectangle` with `MouseArea` in it).

Comment: Here you can find a QML TreeView for QtControls 2: https://github.com/Daguerreo/QMLTreeView

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a mock `AppTreeView` which basically uses Column with `Repeater`. Inside the Repeater, we have a Loader which can instantiate another instance of `AppTreeView`. As you click the `Button` it updates the `Repeater` model which can create/destroy delegates simulating the expansion/collapsing of the TreeView. The JavaScript object is traversed accordingly.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    property var m: ({
        text: "Springfield People",
        children: ["simpsons", "flanders"],
        "simpsons": {
            text: "Simpsons",
            children: ["homer", "marge"],
            "homer": {
                text: "Homer Simpson",
                children: ["bart", "lisa", "maggie"],
                bart : { text: "Bart Simpson" },
                lisa : { text: "Lisa Simpson" },
                maggie: { text: "Maggie Simpson" }
            },
            "marge": { text: "Marge Simpson" }
        },
        "flanders": {
            text: "Flanders",
            children: ["ned", "maude"],
            "ned": {
                text: "Ned Flanders",
                children: ["rod", "todd"],
                "rod": { text: "Rod Flanders" },
                "todd": { text: "Todd Flanders" }
            },
            "maude": { text: "Maude Flanders" }
        }
    })
    AppTreeView {
        model: m
    }
}

//AppTreeView.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Column {
    id: tv
    property var model
    property var text: (model && model.text) || "root"
    Button {
        id: checkBox
        text: tv.text
        icon.source: checked ? "chevron-down.svg" : "chevron-right.svg"
        checkable: true
    }
    Repeater {
        model: checkBox.checked ? tv.model.children : 0
        delegate: Column {
            x: 30 
            Loader { id: loader }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                let m = { name: modelData, value: modelData, nodes: [ ] };
                if (modelData in tv.model) m = tv.model[modelData];
                loader.setSource("AppTreeView.qml",
                {
                    model: m,
                    text: m.text || modelData
                } );
            }
        }
    }
}

// chevron-right.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="black" d="M 16 8 L 24 16 L 16 24"/>
</svg>

// chevron-down.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="black" d="M 8 16 L 24 16 L 16 24"/>
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: How can we extend this code to collapse , all children if the root is collapsed? also , can be change the checkbox to some collapse icon?

Comment: @Vkoder I've updated the answer to have a new "Root" parent collapsed that results in hiding the original children. I've switched the CheckBox for a Button and I use `icon.source` to set `"chevron-right.svg"` or `"chevron-down.svg"` accordingly.