# QML Nested Menu doesn't appear when loaded with Loader

Tags: qt, qml

I'm able to render MenuItem components when using a loader, but am struggling to get nested Menu components to display when using Loader.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle{
   Component {
        id: testMenuItem

            MenuItem {
                text: "dynamic non-nested item"
            }

    }

    Component {
        id: testNestedMenu
        Menu {
            title: "nested menu component"
            MenuItem {
                text: "nested item"
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: testButton
        text: "Test"
        onClicked: testMenu.open()

        Menu {
            id: testMenu

            // hard-coded menu item displays correctly
            MenuItem {
                text: "hard-coded item"
            }

            // hard-coded nested menu displays correctly
            Menu {
                title: "hard-coded nested menu"
                MenuItem {
                    text: "nested item"
                }
            }

            // dynamically-loaded single item displays correctly
            Loader {
                sourceComponent: testMenuItem
            }

            // dynamically-loaded nested menu doesn't display at all
            Loader {
                sourceComponent: testNestedMenu
            }
        }

    }
}
```

How can I get testNestedMenu to display using a Loader?

If you're wondering why I need to use Loader here, I'm trying to build a multi-level menu which will be built dynamically based on tree-shaped data (nested arrays basically). I plan on using Instantiator (iterating over my model), and Loader (in order to properly render a Menu or MenuItem component depending on whether the data item has children or not).

Comment: Can't you use`addMenu()`, `insertMenu()` and `removeMenu()` for creating the dynamic structure you're talking about?

Comment: While not exactly the same, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311571/881441 I use recursive Loaders to create a dynamic nested control. In that answer, I wanted to mimic a TreeView, but, it could be adapted to create a nested Menu.

Comment: @iam_peter I may resort to that.  But for now I’m trying to understand the behavior in order to better understand QML.

Comment: @Stephen_Quan thanks.  Your solution is similar to what I’ve arrived at, but like I said above, understanding why the technique I’m attempting fails is important to me.  Otherwise I feel like I’m just trying stuff at random until I find something that works.

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote the answer to use `Repeater` in conjunction with `addMenu()` and `addItem()` to populate the a `Menu` dynamically:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    property var menuDef: [
        {
            "name": "item1",
            "type": "menuItem"
        },
        {
            "name": "item2",
            "type": "menu",
            "subitems": ["submenu2a", "submenu2b"]
        },
        {
            "name": "item3",
            "type": "menuItem"
        },
        {
            "name": "item4",
            "type": "menu",
            "subitems": ["submenu4a", "submenu4b"]
        }
    ]
    Button {
        text: "Go!"
        onClicked: testMenu.open()
        Menu {
            id: testMenu
            Repeater {
                model: menuDef
                delegate: Item {
                    property Menu tempMenu: Menu {
                        title: modelData.name
                        Repeater {
                            model: modelData.subitems
                            MenuItem {
                                text: modelData
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    property MenuItem tempMenuItem: MenuItem {
                        text: modelData.name
                    }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        if (modelData.type === "menuItem" )
                            testMenu.addItem(tempMenuItem);
                        else
                            testMenu.addMenu(tempMenu);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

<strike>I tested your code and variations on it and yes, there seems to be a problem with instantiating new `Menu` child components. It's not a problem with `Loader` per se, even using `Instantiator` or `Repeater` shows the same issue.</strike>

Instead of `Loader` you can use `Qt.createQmlObject` to create the entire `Menu`. Note that in the dynamic creation, I use `Component.onCompleted: open()` to force the `Menu` to become visible immediately after it was created.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    id: page
    Button {
        text: "Test"
        onClicked: createTestMenu()
    }
    function createTestMenu() {
        const newObject = Qt.createQmlObject(`
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Menu {
    MenuItem { text: "item one" }
    Menu {
        title: "item two"
        MenuItem { text: "item two-a" }
    }
    MenuItem { text: "item three" }
    Menu {
        title: "item four"
        MenuItem { text: "item four-a" }
        MenuItem { text: "item four-b" }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: open()
}
`,
           page,
           "myDynamicMenu"
       )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply Stephen. I'm a little surprised by how hard this is turning out to be. It seems like a pretty straightforward thing to do. Using the backing data to generate a string, which is then used in the javascript API does seem like a possible approach, one that I hadn't considered, but a very roudabout solution, and makes me wonder if I'm asking too much of QML. Is it uncommon to do this much customization on components? Should I just use what's offered out of the box and not try anything fancy?

Comment: Is it common to generate QML code in another language (javascript here), rather than using the QML api directly? This feels like a huge red flag to me, but if this really is a common and idiomatic way to work, I could consider going against my instincts.

Comment: @morgancodes I rewrote the answer

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I'll give you a checkmark :) Can you tell me what the advantage of using the declarative API, combined with the javascript API is here? Seems like it might be simpler to just do everything in JavaScript.