# How to display data while respecting their hierarchy in QML?

Tags: python, mysql, qt, qml

I'm trying to display data retrieved from an SQL table in my Qt application using Python for the backend and QML for the frontend.

So, I have a ListModel in my QML with the following fields: idData, DataName, DataParentId. "DataParentId" represents the "IdData" identifier of each data's parent, and "DataParentId" is null if the data has no parent.

I'm looking for the best way to display this data, allowing the selection of multiple data via a checkbox placed next to each data. I would also like to integrate a button to hide or show the children of a data.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for your help

I tried to modify my SQL query to pre-sort the data in the right order and include a field indicating the depth in the tree for each data point. However, with this approach, I'm struggling to incorporate a button to hide the children of a data point.

Comment: *"I'm looking for the best way to display this data"* -- There's no such thing as a "best way". How do you want it to be displayed? In a [TreeView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-treeview.html)?

Comment: Well a (custom?) Treeview would suit pretty well since it contains the features I want, such as indentation and a button to show or hide a data's childrens, but I can't find a way to use my current data with a TreeView. I should also mention that I use Qt 5.15

Comment: Displaying the data as a tree is definitely something that I want to use anyway.

Comment: Is there a possibility of cyclic dependency? Is the data minute or sparse? These questions will allow you to answer whether you are able to prewalk your dataset else to only walk your dataset on demand. Typically one would go for the latter, with SQL statements being executed for everytime a tree node is being expanded.

Comment: @StephenQuan As a non-native english speaker, I may not correctly understand what you mean by minute or sparse data, so let me give you a more detailed explanation on how my dataset works.
I use a sql database where all the data used by my Qt application is stored. Using python, I am able to open a connection between my database and my app, and store whatever data I want in a ListModel. In this case, I store the following data in dataModel : idData: int ; DataName : varchar(200) ; DataParentId : int

Comment: You might want to know about this repo: https://github.com/diracsbracket/qmltreeview2/tree/master. Maybe you can add a property `child_count` next to `depth`, with that you should be able to recursively count the items you need to show/hide when clicking the expand button

Comment: @kirogu is your data minute, small, less than a thousand records (1000). Or is your data sparse, i.e. more than a million records (1000000). If it is the former, we could consider loading everything. If it's the latter, then, it would not be possible to load everything. Hence, the need to load on-demand subsections of your data through subqueries. Also, do you have cyclic data, e.g. chicken's parent is an egg, egg's parent is a chicken, ... - if cyclic data is possible, do you expect the UI/UX to expand indefinitely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider a part of the Simpson's and the Flander's family:

- Homer Simpson

  - Bart Simpson
  - Lisa Simpson
- Ned Flanders

  - Todd Flanders
  - Rod Flanders

We could model this in SQL as:

| dataId | dataName | dataParentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Homer | 0 |
| 1002 | Bart | 1001 |
| 1003 | Lisa | 1001 |
| 1004 | Ned | 0 |
| 1005 | Todd | 1004 |
| 1006 | Rod | 1004 |

To turn this into a hierarchy, we would need recursion that determines the following 3 SQL queries:

- SELECT * FROM dataTable WHERE parentId = 0 -- Homer, Ned
- SELECT * FROM dataTable WHERE parentId = 1001 -- Bart, Lisa
- SELECT * FROM dataTable WHERE parentId = 1004 -- Todd, Rod

If we were to represent the above data in an hierarchical Javascript object, it might look like this:

```js
{
  "dataId": 0,
  "children": ["Homer","Ned"],
  "Homer": {
    "dataId": 1001,
    "children": ["Bart","Lisa"],
    "Bart": {"dataId": 1002},
    "Lisa": {"dataId": 1003}
  },
  "Ned": {
    "dataId": 1004,
    "children": ["Todd", "Rod"],
    "Todd": {"dataId": 1005},
    "Rod": {"dataId": 1006}
  }
}
```

To render that Javascript object, a solution described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74311571/881441

Here's a working sample QML project:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    title: "SQL to QML TreeView"
    property list<var> dataTable: ([])
    function insertRecord(dataId, dataName, dataParentId) {
        // INSERT INTO dataTable VALUES (:dataId, :dataName, :dataParentId)
        dataTable.push([dataId, dataName, dataParentId]);
    }
    function insertRecords(records) {
        for (const [dataId, dataName, dataParentId] of records) 
            insertRecord(dataId, dataName, dataParentId)
    }
    function selectRecords(dataParentId) {
        // SELECT * FROM dataTable WHERE DataParentId = :dataParentId
        return dataTable.filter(d => d[2] === dataParentId);
    }
    function selectRecursive(dataParentId) {
        let obj = ({ dataId: dataParentId });
        for (const [dataId, dataName, _dataParentId] of selectRecords(dataParentId)) {
            if (! ("children" in obj) ) obj.children = [ ];
            obj.children.push(dataName); 
            obj[dataName] = selectRecursive(dataId);
        }
        return obj;
    }
    TextEdit {
        id: dbgText
        anchors.fill: parent
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        visible: dbg.checked
        clip: true
    }
    AppTreeView {
        id: appTreeView
        visible: !dbg.checked
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        insertRecords( [
            [ 1001, "Homer", 0 ],
            [ 1002, "Bart", 1001 ],
            [ 1003, "Lisa", 1001 ],
            [ 1004, "Ned", 0 ],
            [ 1005, "Todd", 1004 ],
            [ 1006, "Rod", 1004 ]
        ] );
        let m = selectRecursive(0);
        appTreeView.model = m;
        dbgText.text = JSON.stringify(m, undefined, 2)
    }
    footer: Frame {
        CheckBox { id: dbg; text: "Debug" }
    }
}

//AppTreeView.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Column {
    id: tv
    property var model
    property var text: (model && model.text) || "root"
    Button {
        id: checkBox
        text: tv.text
        icon.source: checked ? "chevron-down.svg" : "chevron-right.svg"
        checkable: true
    }
    Repeater {
        model: checkBox.checked ? tv.model.children : 0
        delegate: Column {
            x: 30 
            Loader { id: loader }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                let m = { name: modelData, value: modelData, nodes: [ ] };
                if (modelData in tv.model) m = tv.model[modelData];
                loader.setSource("AppTreeView.qml",
                {
                    model: m,
                    text: m.text || modelData
                } );
            }
        }
    }
}

// chevron-right.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="black" d="M 16 8 L 24 16 L 16 24"/>
</svg>

// chevron-down.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="black" d="M 8 16 L 24 16 L 16 24"/>
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Note the above assumes that the data is small enough to be completely downloaded and constructed as an in-memory Javascript object. This assumption will no longer be true if the data is (1) too large (such as more than 1000 records), or (2) the data has cyclic dependencies (e.g. chicken-egg-chicken-egg-...). To address such issues, the algorithm needs to be changed to run the SQL commands on demand for paging (to show a screenful worth of data at a time), and/or to show one expanded node at a time.

Comment: Thanks, I successfully made a custom TreeView component using your code and it works great ! I'm just working on implementing a checkbox for each data and retrieving the list of checked data, I'll eventually figure it out ! :)